# Printing h1 titles without tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Using Beautiful Soup 4 I am trying to print h1 content without the tags.

I am using python 3.6 and Beautiful Soup 4.

```
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    html = urlopen('https:/place_holder.com/')
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')
    headings = bs.find_all('h1')
    print(headings)
```

Expected results:

First Title
Second Title
Third Title

Actual results:
Each of the titles is preceded and ending by the h1 tag

Comment: It should be  https://place_holder.com/

Not  https:/place_holder.com/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hacky solution:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen('https:/place_holder.com/')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')
headings = bs.find_all('h1')

#New
headings = headings.replace('<h1>', '')
headings = headings.replace('</h1>', '')

print(headings)
```

On an unnecessary note:

You want `https://place_holder.com/`

Not      `https:/place_holder.com/`

Comment: This will not work because the title text is only obtained after executing the following command: headings = bs.find_all('h1') instruction.

Comment: Please put what your script prints out... I must have misunderstood

Comment: It comes with errors. Here is one of them: 
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'replace'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Answer (score 1):

the key method you are looking for is `Tag.get_text()`.

For example:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen('http://example.com/')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')
headings = bs.find_all('h1')
for h in headings:
    print(h.get_text()) # This will print the text between the tags
```